# How can properly verify a user is 18 or older in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation

I want to validate whether a user's age (`birth_date`) is 18+, this is my current code though it isn't working:

```py
...
def min_date():
    return (date.today() - timedelta(days=6570))

class User(BaseModel, RemovabledModel, AbstractUser):
 birth_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name=_('birth date'),
        help_text=_('Birth date'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(
                limit_value=min_date(),
                message=("User must be 18 or older")
            ),
        ]
    )
```

This runs and is functional, but I can still set a user's age to today's date without the application throwing any error message like it would with other validators.

Edit: In case it is relevant, this is related validator:

```
def min_date(): 
    return (date.today() - timedelta(days=6570)) 

class SignUpSerializer(serializers.Serializer): 
    birth_date = serializers.DateField( 
        write_only=True, 
        required=True, 
        validators=[ 
            MinValueValidator( 
                limit_value=min_date(), 
                message=("User must be 18 or older") ),
        ] 
    )
```

Comment: How do you validate the user input? Can you show the view/template/... that you use to let the user enter the data, and how that is handled?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem, the user can register using a serialized API, but I'm currently testing it from the Django admin dashboard. The serializer itself does have an identical validator.

Comment: can you share the serializer?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem,
```
def min_date():
    return (date.today() - timedelta(days=6570))

class SignUpSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
birth_date = serializers.DateField(
        write_only=True,
        required=True,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(
                limit_value=min_date(),
                message=("User must be 18 or older")
            ),
        ]
    )
```

Comment: please *edit* the question, together with the (view)set and perhaps the POST request you are using?

Comment: This is a terrible way to implement date validation on the model itself; as you will make a migration every day you restart the application - because the date changes. Maybe this can be done inside a `clean` method instead?

Comment: @nigel239, how would that work? and why would I need to migrate it? Isn't the minValue only referenced when needed? I might have been approaching this wrongly from the get-go then.

Comment: @Grimidk On the date field in the `User` model; you are calling the `min_date()` function inside the validator, say you were to migrate. You head off for the day. Then the next day; you get back to development; you makemigrations, migrate; and it should say no changes made, but there is a change to the date field. The date inside the min_date function will be incremented.

Comment: @nigel239, I would've thought that the min_date value itself wouldn't be saved. What should I use then?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the validation on the model like so (This also means you can omit the custom field from your serializer):

```
def min_date():
    return (date.today() - timedelta(days=6570))

class User(BaseModel, RemovabledModel, AbstractUser):
 birth_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name=_('birth date'),
        help_text=_('Birth date'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if self.birth_date > min_date():
             # raise validation error here
```

[Relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)
[Custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

How it's currently set up on the model:

On the date field in the User model; you are calling the min_date() function inside the validator, say you were to migrate.
You head off for the day.
Then the next day; you get back to development; you makemigrations, migrate; and it should say no changes made, **but there is** a change to the date field.
The date inside the min_date function will be incremented.

The migration doesn't know you are calling a function in this case; it just *sees* the value.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a specific clean method `clean_birth_date` instead of using a generic `clean` method?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, it would be. Go complain to the django devs, as this is not a feature on models; but is on forms. :) (Sorry if this comes across as rude, I do not mean to be.) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: Ah, I see.  I should have realized this was model validation vs form validation.